# Stop death animation after respawn in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I have a player that will start a "hurt" animation when he collides with an enemy. After 2 seconds he will respawn back to his starting position, but the "hurt" animation doesn't stop. It just keeps on playing even when the player is moving around.

This is my whole Player Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.0f;
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;
    [HideInInspector] public bool facingRight = true;
    private float minX = -10.5f;
    private float maxX = 10.5f;
    public int count;
    public Text countText;
    private Animator anim;
    public GameObject NECText;
    public GameObject WinText;
    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        transform.position = new Vector3(-10.0f, -2.32f, 0);
        count = 0;
        countText.text = "Coins: " + count.ToString();
        NECText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        WinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
        Death();
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if(horizontalInput > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(horizontalInput < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) //fix unlimited jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if(transform.position.x < minX)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (minX, transform.position.y, 0);
        }
        else if(transform.position.x > maxX)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(maxX, transform.position.y, 0);
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= -4.25f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isHurt", true);
            Invoke("Respawn", 2f);
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isHurt", true);
            Invoke("Respawn", 2f);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
        {
            collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count++;
            countText.text = "Coins: " + count.ToString();
        }
        else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Chest" && count < 3)
        {
            NECText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(NECText, 5.0f);
        }
        else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Chest" && count == 3)
        {
            WinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(WinText, 5.0f);
            anim.SetBool("isWinning", true);
        }
    }

    void Respawn()
    {
        Destroy(player);
        Instantiate(player, new Vector3(-10.0f, -2.32f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        anim.SetBool("isHurt", false);
    }
}
```

I know it's probably very messy but it's my first game without a tutorial so it's tough.

Comment: `anim.SetBool("isHurt", false);` is not working? If so, you really need to fix your animation or add "idle" animation. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7EIp-OqVyk) is an official animator tutorial that covers that.

Comment: Put more information regarding when you are spawning? Secondly why are you destorying new player object just when instantiating? Wont that mean your player is just same old player and not new one. Maybe first move the `Destory(player);` before `Instantiate(player, new Vector3(-10.0f, -2.32f, 0), Quaternion.identity);` and see if it works. I think that should be your problem

Comment: @killer_mech The problem is that when I put Destroy(player) first or if I just don't include it at all the player will die and respawn at the starting point but will immediately fall off the level( through the ground).

Comment: @Deltox can you include all the necessary scripts then? right now its difficult to point out the issue because the scripts are not complete

Comment: @killer_mech added the whole player script

Comment: `public GameObject player;` this is a prefab right? Does the prefab contains the script Player attached to it? If so then your code needs reworking. Gamestate variables must be kept in different script then player state variables. And `Destroy(player);` should come afterwards

Comment: As for player falling what you can do is if you are using old gameobject without destorying it then the force you applied make sure it is zero. It can be possible that the force applied on it might make fall off the ground

Comment: @killer_mech Thanks a lot for your help so far! Can you just explain a little bit more about the gamestate variables? Which ones exactly and what I should do with them? It's pretty hard understanding all of this

Comment: The variables `public int count;`
`public Text countText;`
`public GameObject NECText;`
`public GameObject WinText; ` should be put in different script like gamemanager script. These values are not related to player rather just related to your entire game. If something happens to your player script your count will be lost. Unless that is intentional. Other values are just showing some UI for which you need to search for them everytime you instantiate your player object. Better to put them in game manager where you can access it and just display the values instead of changing every instance.

Comment: Another way you can go about is changing your `Respawn()` function. Instead of instantiating the player prefab you can reuse the same prefab and just keep on adjusting its values. Here in this case you wont need to create separate class to store the above mentioned values. You just say like this 
`anim.SetBool("isHurt", false);
transform.position = new Vector3(-10.0f, -2.32f, 0);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0;`
and this should solve your problem if you rework your respawn code

Comment: @killer_mech ahh it worked, thank you so much!! Thanks for the other info too!

Comment: I see. I will add it as answer then. Please mark and close the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussions in comments above OP had trouble related to **Repsawn()** function.

> Another way you can go about is changing your **Respawn()** function.
>   Instead of instantiating the player prefab you can reuse the same
>   prefab and just keep on adjusting its values. Here in this case you
>   wont need to create separate class to store the above mentioned
>   values. You just say like this

```
void Respawn()
{
    anim.SetBool("isHurt", false);
    transform.position = new Vector3(-10.0f, -2.32f, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0; 
}
```

> and this should solve
>   your problem if you rework your respawn code

By changing the respawn code to reuse only single gameobject the issue seems to be resolved.